# How to reset screen when click item menu in Drawer Navigator 3.0

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I have Drawer Navigator of React navigation, when i click item menu, for example:

1: click item A(screen A) -> fetch some data on server from componentDidMount, input some data to InputText,...

2: open drawer menu and click item B(screen B), then open menu again and click item A(screen A) -> some data i fetched before still there and not reload, **even some data i inputed before still there too, not reset**.

I am using react-navigation 3.1

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation'

<ScrollView>
         <DrawerItems {...this.props}
                      onItemPress={({route, focused}) => {
                        console.log(route)
                        // this.resetStack(route, focused)
                        this.props.onItemPress({ route, focused })
                        //i try to reset at there but nothing
                      }}
         />
```

So Anyone know how to resolve that? thanks

**Update: I found the solution for this**

just using:

```
resetStack = (name, focused) => {
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'MenuBar' })],
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
    this.props.navigation.navigate(NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'MenuBar',
      action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: name.routeName })
    }))
  }
```

```
...
<DrawerItems {...this.props}
                       onItemPress={({route, focused}) => {
                         this.resetStack(route, focused)
                       }}
          />
```

Not a best solution but i can not found another better :)

Comment: where you fetch your data from server ... when rendering Screen A ? ... could you include your code

Comment: yes, when render screen A, but not only fetch data, i updated this post, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        yourData: null
    };

    fetchData = () = {
        // get some data
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // you fetched data here:
        const data = fetchData();
        this.setState({ yourData: data });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // check if you need to re-fetch data ... in case of new props:
        if (needToReloadData) {
            const data = fetchData();
            this.setState({ yourData: data });
        }

        if(needToReset) {
            this.setState({ yourData: null });
        }
    }
}
```

`componentDidMount` event of screen A is called once you chose it from your drawer ... and then after clicking another screen like screen B ==> screen A gets unmounted from the screen ... that's why when you **re-open** screenA ==> `componentDidMount` event of screenA is called once more...

in order to solve your issue of reloading data when clicking, you need to include your reset logic in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

1. componentDidMount event. // will be executed on first click.
2. componentWillReceiveProps // will be executed on next subsequent clicks

Comment: Yes, i know how to reset data when fetch api, but its mot my problem, fetch data just a example, i mean when i input anything in screen A, or i scroll to the bottom of screen A, and when i return screen A by click item in Menu of navigation, it not change, not reset

Comment: that;s because your ScreenA is already **MOUNTED** ... and then you need to place your reset logic  in `componentWillReceiveProps` event ... like clearing state data ... or scrollTo top... whatever you want to do has to be done in this event handler ... there's no way you could **Unmount** a screen and **remount** it again to get a fresh look of your screen .. and most of the time clearing your `state` that your rendering depend upon would reset your screen to it's default view

Comment: oh, thank you, look like react native get more difficult than native, in android not like that :D

Comment: @Mr.Tuan as I mentioned in the comment above ... most of the time **resetting component state** is just a matter of resetting component `state` (cause it should be  your **single source of truth**) which IMO a more simple and elegant solution ... but glad you find a satisfying solution anyway...